# php transaction error, i always get a rollback error

Tags: php, pdo

im trying to update 2 tables at once. from my research i have to use a transaction for this:

```
protected function myUpdateFunction(){
        try{
            $this->connect()->beginTransaction();

        $itemID = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemID');
        $itemName = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemName');
        $itemDescription = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemDescription');
        $itemPrice = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemPrice');
        $itemStock = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemStock');
        $updateItemBtn = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemBtn');

        $sql = "UPDATE oopphp_items SET itemName = ?, itemDescription = ?, itemPrice = ?, itemStock = ? WHERE itemID = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $itemName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $itemDescription, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $itemPrice, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $itemStock, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(5, $itemID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();


        //wishlist
        $itemID_fk = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemID');
        $itemName_fk = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemName');
        $itemDescription_fk = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemDescription');
        $itemPrice_fk = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'updateItemPrice');

        $sql = "UPDATE oopphp_wishlist SET itemName_fk = ?, itemDescription_fk = ?, itemPrice_fk = ? WHERE itemID_fk = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $itemName_fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $itemDescription_fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(3, $itemPrice_fk, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(4, $itemID_fk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $this->connect()->commit();
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
                echo $e->getMessage();
                $this->connect()->rollBack();

        }
    }
```

i get the following error:

**Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: There is no active transaction**

when i tried looking for answers they all said to put it inside a try-catch, which i already did. all examples i could find do it like this. as seen here: [PHP PDO - There is no active transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41392982/php-pdo-there-is-no-active-transaction)

i also found some people suggest adding these to the database file:

```
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);
```

which also hasent done anything.

now if i just remove the code inside the catch() then the error goes away and i both my update queries work.

the only difference i could spot is that all examples dont have their database connection as a function.

so where i do:

```
$this->connect()->beginTransaction();
```

they do:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
```

and obviously same for commit() and rollBack(). though i cant imagine this being the problem. especially when it works perfectly if i remove the catch() content.

this is where i got the code from: https://thisinterestsme.com/php-pdo-transaction-example/

i seem to have the same code apart from the connect() vs $pdo.

my connect function:

```
protected function connect(){
        try{
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . $this->DB_NAME;
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->DB_USER, $this->DB_PASS);

            //setting default fetch mode
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            //setting errors for exceptions for try/catch
            $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
            return $pdo;
        }
        catch(PDOException $error){
            echo 'Connection error: ' . $error->getMessage();
        }
        finally{
            //$pdo = null;
        }
    }
```

i fixed it with the help of the comment, and a final note at the end if someone sees this later:
this line i mentioned: **$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, FALSE);**

made it so my CRUD didnt work anymore. the other 2 setAttribute() didnt cause errors with anything at this moment.

Comment: so , do you have real transactions where you put a comment , or not ?   if you did nothing beteween the begin and commit, the exception is completely normal. ps, show that code too

Comment: figured it wouldt matter as it worked fine when i removed the catch block. but i added it now. @YvesLeBorg

Comment: what does `connect()` return ?  if it returns a different pdo object each time ... well you know what you get.

Comment: i editted my post to include the connect() function. again this should be very standard.

Comment: Now, do you realize that your connect() function is a very bad idea?

Comment: well its the first time i have problems with it. it is also the first time i use a database connection as a function instead of a variable but other than this it has had the same effect. though an added benefit is that if i do it in a class and function i can use the spl_autoload_register() to autoload it together with all other classes. which is easier than having to include all the class files. do you believe that its bad to use a function for the database connection instead of a variable? @YourCommonSense

Comment: just saw you own https://phpdelusions.net/ and i actually used your guide from https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#transactions as well to see how to make a transaction. as i see you actually commented it on the original post i linked to. so you helped without even knowing! though im still uncertain as to why a function to connect to a database is inherently bad.

Comment: Because it creates a new connection to a database every time it is called. Given there always should be just one connection, there is no point in having a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `connect()`, you get a different PDO object each time. Thus,

```
$this->connect()->beginTransaction(); // pdo object 1

$this->connect()->commit();   // pdo object 4
```

PDO object 4 has no transaction in progress! the Exception is normal.

Quick fix :

in you try block

```
 $pdo = $this->connect();
 $pdo->beginTransaction();
  ....  // replace all $this->connect() by $pdo
 $pdo->commit();
```

Comment: yes this solved it! i did see other people say that exact thing on other posts "you get a different PDO object each time", but wasent sure what could be done. thanks a lot!